# How to avoid Pylance errors for functions with multiple signature for output?

Tags: python, type-hinting, pylance

I am trying to modify my project to be Pylance compliant and I am having the following issue:

Lets say that I have a function of the form:

```py
def foo(a: int) -> int | list[int]:
    if a > 0:
        return a
    else:
        return [a]
```

Then in the code when I call `len(foo(-2))`, Pylance is giving me an error. What is the best way to handle it?

If this helps, here is the real function:

```py
    def read(self, path: Optional[str] = None) -> list[str] | h5py.Datatype | npt.ArrayLike :
        """read
        Wrapper around the __getitem__ of h5py. Directly returns the keys of the sub-groups if 
        the path lead to an h5py.Group, otherwise directly load the dataset.
        
        This allows to get a list of keys to the folders without calling .keys(), 
        and to the data without [()] therefore the way to call the keys or the data are the same.
        And therefore the user does not need to change the call between .keys() and [()] to navigate 
        the hierarchical structure.

        Parameters
        ----------
        path : Optional[str], optional
            Path to the Group or Dataset you want to read. 
            If the value is None, read the root of the folder:
            (should be [datasets, metadata, process] if created with Hystorian), by default None

        Returns
        -------
        list[str] | h5py.Datatype | npt.ArrayLike
            If the path lead to Groups, will return a list of the subgroups, 
            if it lead to a Dataset containing data, it will directly return the data, 
            and if it is an empty Dataset, will return its Datatype.

        """
        if path is None:
            return list(self.file.keys())
        else:
            current = self.file[path]
            if isinstance(current, h5py.Group):
                return list(current.keys())
            if isinstance(current, h5py.Datatype):
                return current
            else:
                return current[()]
```

This function is part of a context manager class which takes an h5py.File as attribute `self.file`, and add extra functions to it. (Like this read function instead of using the `__getitem__` implemented by h5py, which also returns different type of object depending of the path: either an `h5py.Group`, `h5py.Datatype` or `h5py.Dataset`.

Therefore when I call `f.read()` it returns a list of the `h5py.Group` in the root `['datasets', 'metadata', 'process]`, but if I call `f.read('datasets/values')` and values is an `h5py.Dataset` it will directly return the data.

The solution that I might see so far is that for each call of the function `read` I should check the return type. However since the internal of the function is already doing type checking, this seem not ideal.

Another solution would be to use `# type : ignore` but this seems counter productive with implementing pylance in the first place.

What I was thinking is to create three internal functions `_readkey`, `_readdata` and `_readtype` that are then called by `read`, which would be the function called by the API user, but internally I would call the three internal functions. But this also seem to lose a bit the point of `read`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the result deppends ond the input you could resolve this with the [@overload decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload)...

Instead of using the `self.file[path]` add `current` to the function signature and add the three signatures.

```
@overload
def read(self) -> List[str]:
    pass

@overload
def read(self, path: str) -> List[str]:
    pass

@overload
def read(self, current: h5py.Group) -> List[str]:
    pass

@overload
def read(self, current: h5py.Datatype) -> h5py.Datatype:
    pass

@overload
def read(self, current: npt.ArrayLike) -> npt.ArrayLike:
    pass

def read(self, path: Optional[str] = None, current: Optional[Union[h5py.Group, h5py.Datatype, npt.ArrayLike]]) -> Union[List[str], h5py.Datatype, npt.ArrayLike]:
   ...
```

Mixing returns is a bad idea that makes the code harder to understand...

For example `print(len(foo(2)))` raises a `TypeError`...

If you want to use `len(foo(-2))`, you would have to check that the return is a list...

```
res = foo(-2)
if isinstance(res, list):
    print(len(res))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what [`typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) is for. You can define multiple function call signatures that are distinct in their argument types (and optionally their return types). Example:

```py
from typing import Optional, overload


@overload
def read(path: str) -> str: ...


@overload
def read(path: None = None) -> list[str]: ...


def read(path: Optional[str] = None) -> list[str] | str:
    if path is None:
        return ["foo"]
    return "bar"
```

Try it with the type checker of your choice:

```py
from typing_extensions import reveal_type


reveal_type(read())       # "builtins.list[builtins.str]"
reveal_type(read(None))   # "builtins.list[builtins.str]"
reveal_type(read("abc"))  # "builtins.str"
```